# reset all value of controller in flutter with getx packages?

Tags: flutter, dart, state, flutter-get

hi i want to know how te reset all value of controller in [getx packages](https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx) ?

I already tried

`Get.reset();`

but that's not working

Answer (score 2):

`Get.deleteAll();` deletes all Instances Data `Get.delete<ControllerName>();` to delete a particular controller Instance. Also, if you used `GetxService` then call `Get.reset()`.

Answer (score 1):

Get.reset() is for removing all **pages** that you added them in **stack navigator** and it is not for resetting the values of GetXController parameters
if you want to reset controller values you must define your controller **after** build like this:
 `Widget build(BuildContext context) {final MessageController msController = Get.put(MessageController());`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `force: true`:

```
Get.delete<BookAppointmentController>(force: true);
```